# Ubuntu Software application loader doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, software-center

Ubuntu Software application loader doesn't work.

I have two computers running Ubuntu.  I upgraded one from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS with no issues; a clean install from a bootable USB drive (image from Ubuntu), installed extra software apps (c.10 in all) using the Ubuntu Software Centre, restored backed up data, all done in about 30 mins no issues;  working just great.

So I've also upgraded my old laptop to 16.04 LTS using the same bootable USB drive, all looks ok except that the Ubuntu Software Centre doesn't load up at all.  First time it started to come up (unpopulated) then disappeared.  Now it doesn't even load - the icon flashes for a while + hourglass, the nothing.
Invoking gnome-software from the terminal doesn't work either.

I've looked at this forum and the Ubuntu forums for ideas.

So far I've tried:
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software [it does]
sudo apt-get purge gnome-software ubuntu-software
sudo apt autoremove
suto apt install gnome-software ubuntu-software
sudo apt update
-- then rebooted PC

I've tried sudo appstreamcli refresh --force --verbose [don't know what that is supposed to do;  doesn't make a difference]

Can someone please help this non-techie out please. Would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Open the `terminal` application from the Unity launcher, and type `sudo apt-get update`. If you have the `Synaptic` application, start it, and click the `reload` icon. See if those two things fix your problem. Report back.

Comment: I have installed synaptic and run sudo synaptic.  It comes straight up.
I haven't used synaptic before.  eg I want to install GIMP.  Do I just select GIMP or do I have to select other options as well starting with gimp- ?

Comment: Also, I still want to get the Ubuntu Software Centre up and running as I've found this helps in discovering applications I want.

Comment: You did the `sudo apt-get update`, yes? Yes, in Synaptic, first you'd click the reload icon to update its database, then you'd just search for "gimp", checkmark the ones you want installed, and click the apply icon. Also, `Ubuntu Software` and `Ubuntu Software Center`... one replaced the other, so the original one is not used any more... I just forget which way it went... as I upgraded Ubuntu like you did, and I show both... I should probably uninstall the older one.

Comment: I have now solved the problem with help on the Ubuntu LaunchPad forum.
See https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/404472

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's not really clear what fixed it for you, huh?

Comment: Correct!  However I'm happy it all works.  It would be better to understamd why but that would imply more expertise than I have.  It won't keep me awake at night though.

Answer (score 0):

This works:
From terminal (CTRL-ALT-T)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software
sudo apt-get purge gnome-software ubuntu-software
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install gnome-software ubuntu-software
```

rebooted pc

then invoked the updater from the terminal again

```
gnome-software
```

scary for a novice, but it worked for me!

Comment: But not for the questioner! "So far I've tried: sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software [it does] sudo apt-get purge gnome-software ubuntu-software sudo apt autoremove suto apt install gnome-software ubuntu-software sudo apt update -- then rebooted PC".  They've solved it [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/404472)